# How to start a systemd service after user login and stop it before user logout

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, systemd

I have a Fedora 23 Machine.

I have a directory/file synchronizing bash script that synchronizes my local /home directory to a remote directory (in a NAS machine). I run it manually but I would like to create a systemd service and make it more flexible, since other people use my PC with their own user credentials, I 'd like to know when a user is logged in and start my service afterwards.

Is there something I can do from my service's systemd file or will I have to check that from my code in the script?

I only need to make sure that I have access to environment variables (like $USER) and to run it as a service.

My main source of documentation is this link https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html

Comment: Does `systemctl --user` work on F23?

Comment: I guess so, It returns a list and a message `76 loaded units listed`.

Comment: Here's another approach which might work for you: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109270/111707 Write a small Python script which you launch from `.bashrc` on login, then it listens for Gnome logout signal and shuts itself down.

Comment: @IanB Thank you, I will test it. It never hurts to have something like that around.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Use systemd** it already includes support for user sessions, in fact you should already depend on it (unwittingly).

**Create the service directory**

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.local/share/systemd/user
```

**Create edit a service file (vim, gedit, geany - whatever you want)**

```
vim $HOME/.local/share/systemd/user/my.service
```

**It should roughly look like this, if it's a permanent service.**

```
[Unit]
Description=My very own Service
[Service]
Type=simple
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStart=/path/to/start/script arguments
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

**But it sounds like you rather want to trigger it once, then be good with it, so rather use a oneshot configuration like this:**

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
StandardOutput=journal
ExecStart=/path/to/start/script arguments
ExecStop=/path/to/stop/script arguments
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

This of course assumes that your script is executable, i.e.:

```
chmod a+x /path/to/start/script
chmod a+x /path/to/stop/script
```

Else you would need to prepend the path to the respective interpreter:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash /path/to/start/script arguments
```

Now reload systemd (and re-login for the sake of testing)

```
systemctl --user enable my.service # enables the service
systemctl --user # should display your new unit in the list
journalctl --user should show the log
```

If you need more information refer to the [Arch-Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Writing_user_units) for example.
[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu) askubuntu thread has various ideas, including incidentally, mine.

You can extend the behaviour (if you are root) to other users by defining the service globally. In order to do this you would need to create the service file in **/usr/share/systemd/user/** not in **$HOME/.local/share/systemd/user**.

Comment: hi, the answer was good. But it will only work if the service should be started at **first** login and stopped at **last** user session.

Comment: You need the --user flag when enabling the service. "systemctl --user enable my.service"

Comment: Alert - there is no way to tell system NOT to process your .config/systemd/user services until after you log in - meaning it doesn't work if your HOME directory is encrypted until you have entered your password to login.

Answer (score 2):

I know this a few year old, but the answer from anx just helped me out.  So, I guess it's still relevent.  Also, this is more of a comment, but I don't have that privledge so I posting it as an "answer". At any rate...

Running Linux Mint 19, I could not "enable" the service when the script was located in '$HOME/.local/share/systemd/user'.  Attempting to do so always resulted in a error. I could, however, start it up just fine from the '$HOME/.local/share/systemd/user' directory.  After moving the script into '/usr/share/systemd/user/', systemd allowed me to enable it without issue.

Comment: you need to use systemctl --user enable